# Mysterious http Lp requests found in log

Tags: http, security

I've noticed the following in my access log:

```
Oct 28 20:01:55 vm1295 nginx: [] 89.109.42.242 400 "Lp" "-"
Oct 28 20:58:41 vm1295 nginx: [] 82.208.124.184 400 "Lp" "-"
Oct 28 21:14:05 vm1295 nginx: [] 92.54.98.140 400 "Lp" "-"
...
```

The log format is client ip, returned http code, method, user agent. Only a small fraction of the addresses with this behaviour agains my server are on public blacklists.

Is this behaviour of a malicious scanner? If so, what vulnerability does it target?

Comment: That's a bit difficult to follow. Did you dramatically alter the `log_format`? Please post it, rather than describing it.

Comment: Well that is kind of the interesting part, other than that the fields are empty (host, forwarded for, data, ...). The request is really just `Lp`.